# How can I get Magento Each Session values by using Magento frontend cookie value through Web Service?

Tags: magento2, php, session, cookie

We are developing separate home page from Magento and accessing information from Magento through Web Services and will integrate this external home page with existing Magento website.

But on this home page I am facing a problem related to session I have created a **frontend cookie** on this external home page. But I have no idea how can I get **session values** by using frontend cookie value.

I am working on this problem from last 1 week please post your valuable answer from which I can resolve my problem.

Thanks